# Why *.cs files at web server is bad practice?

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis-7

There is a IIS web server 7.0. There is a web app at this server.
Let's assume that web app doesn't contain any errors.
So my question why *.cs files is bad practice at web server?
I can't open cs files in web browser. So except access to source code what is bad in such approach?

Comment: Can you tell us why you would want to do this? Maybe we can better understand the context.

Answer (score 2):

It isn't unheard of for flaws in web servers to be exposed.  For this reason it is generally a good idea to keep your source code, which may contain sensitive or proprietary information, off of the web server.

Comment: That you should probably be taking advantage of publishing rather than xcopy deployment... make sure everything builds and such.

Comment: I've seen many people who stage their web apps with cs files. So why is is bad practice if web server inside company and nobody except a developer can access to him?

Comment: Staging should match Production.

Answer (score 1):

The concern here is that the server could be hacked and if someone was to gain access, then the hacker could obtain your .cs files and thus, your code.  Not being able to open the .cs files in the browser isn't necessarily the main concern.

Likely not something you'd like to happen.  The .cs files aren't needed for the build on the server, so it's just best practice to put only what's needed on the server.

---

The other thing that plays in here is performance.  No matter what is on the server, your code gets compiled.  When you copy the raw code files to the server, these are compiled at run-time.  When you publish/deploy your app, this process pre-compiles your app and then those dlls are put on the server.  This compilation won't need to be done at run-time in this case.

Comment: I'm interested also moment about performance. Is version without cs files is faster rather than with cs files?

Comment: The source can easily be obtain using Reflector or similar tool

Comment: I created test site which paints one month schedule. And I created 2 web apps at my localhost web server (7.0): one is without cs and the second with cs. After 10 reqeusts I don't see difference in performance at all.